# How to get status of uploading file using HttpRequest.sendStream()?

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

I wrote a function whose uploading file to a cloud service. It works well, but I can't figure out how to check the progress of uploading file.

```
suspend fun uploadFile(path: Path) {
    ...
    val asyncFile: AsyncFile = awaitResult { fs.open(path.toString(), OpenOptions(), it) }
    val methodType: HttpMethod = when (link.method.toLowerCase()) {
        "put" -> HttpMethod.PUT
        "post" -> HttpMethod.POST
        else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("Method is not supported")
    }
    val request: HttpRequest<Buffer> = webClient.requestAbs(methodType, link.href)
    val response: HttpResponse<Buffer> = awaitResult { request.sendStream(asyncFile, it) }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the `ReadStream` interface provided by `AsyncFile` with a delegation and in the `handler` method update a counter with the number of bytes emitted by the `AsyncFile` which would tell you how much of the file has been sent.